# Js file is not adding using this code in functions.php

Tags: plugins, theme-development

Sorry i am noob in WordPress. I am using following code in functions.php to add the .js file in wordpress.

```
function your_function_name()
{

   wp_localize_script( 'function', 'my_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'function', get_template_directory_uri().'/my_js_stuff.js', 'jquery', true);

}
add_action('template_redirect', 'your_function_ name');

$dirName = dirname(__FILE__);
$baseName = basename(realpath($dirName));
require_once ("$dirName/MyFunctions.php");

add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_my_option", "get_my_option");
add_action("wp_ajax_get_my_option", "get_my_option");
```

I am using twenty fourteen theme.

Comment: You don't use template_redirect to enqueue JS. The codex is your friend: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: @vancoder i have taken code from this blog http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-use-ajax-with-php-on-your-wp-site-without-a-plugin/

Comment: @vancoder still not working http://i.imgur.com/6z3ifiZ.png

Comment: That's a truly awful tutorial.

Comment: @vancoder Do you know any good tutorial in ajax in wordpress?

Comment: @vancoder I think you meant `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things that confused me when using ajax was that `die()` is **necessary** at the end of the ajax callback function.

Another issue is with the path(s)
If you use `get_template_directory_uri()` and you use a child theme then you get the parents folder.

If you use `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')` and you us a child theme then you get the current child theme being used which I believe would be true for most of the time.

Here is my attempt to show an example that I hope will help you...

Put this in (preferably in a child theme) `functions.php`

```
function jquery_stuff() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('scriptX', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/jsfile.js');    
}
add_action( 'init', 'jquery_stuff');

//tells WP that this an function used for ajax
add_action('wp_ajax_coolContent', 'coolContent'); 

//Used for returning cool content
function coolContent() { 
   $msg = 'cool content';

   //Return content
   echo json_encode($msg);
   die();
}
```

**jQuery** (jsfile.js)

```
var coolContent = $.ajax({            
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
        action: 'coolContent',        //This is the function that should be called on serverside    
    },
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', //tells WP that it is ajax
    dataType: 'json'
});

coolContent.done(function(data) {  
    alert(data); //Should alert text "cool content"
});                        

coolContent.fail(function(ts) {           
    alert(ts.responseText);
});
```